# Looping a selenium webdriver script in java but with different values

Tags: java, loops, selenium

I got this issue. I want to loop in my selenium webdriver this function:

> driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).sendKeys("Example 1");

But i want that every next generated elemented was "Example 2","Example 3","Example 4" etc. and so on. Is there a simple method for that ?

---

OK. I've managed it by making this:

```
int x = 1;
 while (x<20) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).sendKeys("Example" + x);x++; }
```

Comment: This is just a Java loop, not specific to Selenium

Comment: I'm new so maybe I'm little behind on the syntax. But it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
WebElement wE = driver.findElement(By.id("some id"));
for(int i= 1;i<20;i++){
     wE.sendKeys("Example "+ i);
}
```